# PHP Interpreter for Windows

Tags: php

Trying to mess around with PHP, but I don't want to install IIS or Apache and was hoping for a small interpreter that I can pass the scripts to and have them run in like a console or something. Much like Lua does. Does this exist? When I go to download PHP it seems to only talk about running it on IIS or Apache.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a standalone interpreter for windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6868747/814702)

Comment: why don't you run it online http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP can be used on the [command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php). Just download and extract [the executable](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4).

Running can be done 3 ways: a file, supplied code or in an interactive shell

```
php file.php
php -r "echo 'hello';"
php -a
```

You can also install a pre-packaged server (e.g. [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)) or run your code online on various places (e.g. [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/))

Comment: Courtesy to @Eineki for remarking that an interactive shell is also possible.

Answer (score 2):

With PHP 5.1+ you have an interactive shell too:

launch php with -a parameter

```
php.exe -a
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe that PHP v5.4 comes with its own webserver built-in. Install that version and you should be fine. Though I really would like to know why you have problem with installing Apache (IIS sucks though).

EDIT:
As a few others have said, you can run PHP from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

check out [easyphp](http://www.easyphp.org/), a server for php development

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/cli

Alternatively, you can write your PHP scripts as you would normally (with some limitations),

And use the following command line:

```
C:\php.exe -f "D:\phpFile.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

dtech's answer seems most fitting for the simple script-running things you're looking for. If you decide you want an actual web-server, with as little setup as possible, look at ["XAMPP"](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).